# Appending strings to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Condicional{
    public static String getNaipe(String carta){
        String[] partes = carta.split("");
        String[] nuevaCarta;
        switch (partes[0]){
            case "a": nuevaCarta.append("As");
        }
        return nuevCarta[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String notacion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca la notacion de la carta:");
        String significado = getNaipe(notacion);
        System.out.println(significado);
    }
}
```

I am trying to make an array where i will append 2 words strings but it marks an error. I try using StringBuffer but i don't quite understand how it works and apparently is not the same as an array.

It returns this error:

> condicional.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>               case "a": nuevaCarta.append("As");
>                                   ^
>     symbol:   method append(String)
>     location: variable nuevaCarta of type String[]
>   1 error

Comment: Java arrays are fixed size. You cannot extend them. Use an `ArrayList<String>` instead.

Comment: Are you trying to append to a string or an array of strings?

Comment: I want to append a string

Comment: *"... it marks an error."* You should include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different data structure. `Arrays` have a fixed length when you create them, so you can't add more elements afterwards and make them longer. You need a `mutable` object so that you can continue to add new elements to it, like an `ArrayList<String>`.

Also, you may want to use [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).